# How do I place an object with UI buttons in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to place an object in-game. I have a UI button to make the object appear, but as Unity only runs the function triggered by the button one time, the engine doesn't continuously move the object to the position of the mouse, which is what I want it to do. How do I fix it?
This is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlaceObjectsWithUI : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject placeableObjectPrefab;

    private GameObject currentPlaceableObject;

    public void PlaceHouse()
    {
        if (currentPlaceableObject == null)
        {
            currentPlaceableObject = Instantiate(placeableObjectPrefab);
        }

        else
        {
            Destroy(currentPlaceableObject);
        }

        if (currentPlaceableObject != null)
        {
            MoveCurrentPlaceableObjectToMouse(); //This is the function I want to be repeated
            ReleaseIfClicked();
        }
    }

    private void MoveCurrentPlaceableObjectToMouse()
    {
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        RaycastHit hitInfo;

        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hitInfo))
        {
            currentPlaceableObject.transform.position = hitInfo.point;
            currentPlaceableObject.transform.rotation = Quaternion.FromToRotation(Vector3.up, hitInfo.normal);
        }
    }

    private void ReleaseIfClicked()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            currentPlaceableObject = null;
        }
    }
}
```

I tried a while-loop to make Unity run the code until the mouse is clicked, but then Unity freezes. I think it gets stuck in the while-loop.

Comment: You could use the button to set something true on the target object, or use it to attach a script to the object that would actually perform the move object to mouse location option for which you are looking

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're after is the Update method? If you place the final if statement found within PlaceHouse() into the Update method, then it will constantly be checked.

Try adding this:

```
private void Update()
{
  if (currentPlaceableObject != null)
  {
    MoveCurrentPlaceableObjectToMouse();
    ReleaseIfClicked();
  }
}
```

Comment: Already treedt that, but then c# makes a function called 'Update', and not the Update- method

Comment: Yep, that is what an update method is. As long as your script is a MonoBehaviour (which it is), all you need to do is create a function called Update() (the capital is essential).

As long as the gameobject that script is attached to is active in the inspector, Unity will recognise the Update method and call it automatically every frame.

If it not working make sure that the method is named exactly Update(). Also make sure that the gameobject is active. And make sure the script component is also active.

Comment: You can also add this line of code inside the Update method like so, to test if the Update method is working:

private void Update() { Debug.Log("TESTING"); }

This should print "TESTING" to your console every frame.